# Ember.js: model interaction in controller or route?

Tags: ember.js

Is it considered Ember.js best practice to keep model interactions -- creation, say -- in the route, or the controller?

An example: the following CoffeeScript works fine, and also works if the 'save' logic is moved into a controller. Is one practice preferred over the other, and if so, why?

```
App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.User.createRecord()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
  events: {
    save: (user) ->
      user.on "didCreate", @, () -> 
        @transitionTo 'users.show', user
      @get('store').commit()
  }
```

Comment: Does it make sense for the router to contain *logic* relating to a particular controller (and presumably model)? What happens if there happens to be no router in a particular usage (or testing) situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if an action affects state just in a particular controller, or the model that that controller fronts, then you should handle it in the controller. If it affects broader application state (i.e. another controller), or results in a route transition, or should be handled by different logic based on the state of the app, it should be handled in the router.